# Bind NSString to sqlite3 sql statement

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

Can you guys tell me how to bind a nsstring to a sqlite3 sql statement?

```
NSString *date = @"test date";
char const *sqlStatement = sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE facts SET alreadyRead = '%q' WHERE id=%d", date, factId);
```

%q doesnt work for a string
%d works for an nsinteger

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not use fmdb? (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *date = @"test date";
char const *sqlStatement = sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE facts SET alreadyRead = '%q' WHERE id=%d", [date UTF8String], factId);
```